# myDate.toLocaleString() not properly formatted for any other language than English

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, localization

I am currently sending dates to email templates and I need to format those dates according to the recipient's language.
I am using toLocaleString() function and it works like a charm for English but not for other languages I tried.

I tried using moment or luxon to format the date but I guess either my code is somehow wrong or they both rely on vanilla toLocaleString() function because I encounter the same issue.

my .js file:

```
   let options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
   return email.send({
      template: 'file-expiration',
      message: {
         to: to,
      },
      locals: {
         fileUuid: fileUuid,
         expireAt: expireAt.toLocaleString('fr-FR', options),
         locale: 'fr',
      },
   });
```

my .pug file:

```
= `${t('mail.file_expiration.line_1', {name: `${name}`, expireAt: `${expireAt}`})}`
```

Expected:

- with en-US: Sunday, September 22, 2019
- with fr-FR: dimanche 22 septembre 2019

Actuel:

- with en-US: Sunday, September 22, 2019
- with fr-FR: 2019 M09 22, Sun

I also tried 'it-IT' and 'es-ES' with same result as for 'fr-FR'

Does anyone has an idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Got a different but still incorrect result [here](https://repl.it/repls/ScentedEarlySolution) - using your date and options, it returns `Sunday, September 22, 2019` even if the language is passed in as `fr-FR`. Firefox returns `"dimanche 22 septembre 2019" ` using the same code as does Chrome. So my only guess is that the Node environment has to somehow be configured with more locales.

Comment: There is no reliable way to determine a user's preferred language without asking them. Even then, you don't know the date format they prefer either, so maybe ask that also. It used to be common to allow users to set preferences for preferred language and format, but for some reason that simple system seems to be eschewed these days. I find *toLocaleString* unsatisfactory to the point of being almost useless. It makes assumptions that everyone who uses a particular language wants dates in a particular format, which is not supported in reality.

Comment: Hope these helps https://github.com/unicode-org/full-icu-npm#readme, https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html#intl_options_for_building_node_js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to those who commented, especially @VLAZ and @User862 because they helped me find the solution.

Their comments helped me understand that my problem came from my Node installation which was built with only 'en-US' locale.

I found this: https://techoverflow.net/2018/09/19/fixing-nodejs-intl-datetimeformat-not-formatting-properly-for-locales/

Which solved everything by simply using [intl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intl) polyfill.

Thanks a lot!