# Luxon .toLocaleString() returning US formatting for non-US locales

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

I'm trying to use Luxon.toLocaleString to format dates for different locales. I'm on Luxon version 3.0.1.

I'm following this example from the [luxon documentation](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetolocalestring):

```
DateTime.now().toLocaleString({ locale: 'en-gb' }); //=> '20/04/2017'
```

My code:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
console.log(DateTime.fromISO('2017-04-20').toLocaleString({ locale: 'en-gb' }));
```

Running this gives me: `4/20/2017`, but the documentation linked above says it should be returning `20/04/2017`. **It similarly is incorrectly returning the US format for other locales that I've tried.**

The cause of my issue seems to be different than the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58010987/5602521) (missing Intl.DateTimeFormat implementation), because running the following code produces results that are consistent with having a proper Intl.DateTimeFormat installation:

```
const df = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('de', {day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric', timeZone: 'UTC'});
console.log(df.format(new Date("2018-08-13T04:00:00.000Z")));
```

gives: `13. August 2018` as expected.

This is running in a React app (create-react-app), if that matters.  (And the React app is served from Node 14, which I understand is supposed to come with `full-icu` installed by default - although since this is running in the browser, I'm not sure if the Node version should matter)

Comment: Looking at the sources of luxon, this seems indeed a bug. The first argument is used as format options, which doesn't expect a locale, while the second argument would expect a locale. Workaround is too pass your argument as second argument. I got lost in the complexity of the luxon code, so I gave up in writing a well-documented answer, but this is the issue in my opinion.

Comment: @trincot—your explanation is correct, so not a bug. ;-)

Comment: It was a bug in the documentation, which has been corrected since I originally posted https://github.com/moment/luxon/issues/1267

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding of the [Luxon documentation](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetolocalestring) for *toLocaleString*.

The first *formatOpts* parameter is defined as:

> formatOpts (any = Formats.DATE_SHORT) {Object} - Intl.DateTimeFormat constructor options and configuration options

The [*Intl.DateTimeFormat* constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) options object is its second parameter and does not have a "locale" option. The language is set by its first parameter (misnamed "locale").

When using Luxon, to change the language used for the "locale", provide it as a parameter of the second *opts* argument.

There are no examples in the Luxon documentation that are consistent with the code in the OP. The only one that comes close is:

```
DateTime.now().toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_FULL, { locale: 'fr' });
```

which passes a default set of valid *Intl.DateTimeFormat* options as the first parameter and sets the language in the second options parameter (i.e. the reverse of *Intl.DateTimeFormat* parameter order).

Probably you want something like:

```js
let DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

console.log(DateTime.fromISO('2017-04-20').toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_SHORT, { locale: 'en-gb' }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.1/luxon.min.js"></script>
```